# Why three gamma matrix between initial and final electron lead to the same helicity?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices, chirality

Quote Peskin page 165

> Suppose that the initial electron is right-handed... Since this term contains three $\gamma$-matrix in (5.97) between $\bar u$ and $u$ the final electron must also be right-handed.

and the amplitude

> $$-ie^2\epsilon_\mu(k)\epsilon^*_\nu(k') \bar u(p')\gamma^\mu\frac{ \gamma^\rho p_\rho- \gamma^\sigma k'_\sigma}{(p-k')^2-m^2}\gamma^\nu u(p)
> \Rightarrow 
> -ie^2\epsilon_\mu(k)\epsilon^*_\nu(k') \bar u_R^\dagger(p')\sigma^\mu \frac{\bar \sigma\cdot(p-k')}{(p-k')^2-m^2}\sigma^\nu u_R(p)\
> $$

Could you explain why that was the case, please?

Comment: Do you know how $u_R$ is defined in terms of $u$? Defining $q:=p-k^\prime$ also helps follow the calculation.

Comment: @J.G. one of the $u_R$ came from the definition basically introduce a projector and communication relationship $\{\gamma ^5,\gamma^\mu\}=0$ seemed to imply that it worked for any number of $\gamma^\mu$, not just the odd ones. But the later the backward scattering with the even gamma matrix changed the helicity so it was confusing.