# The relation of gamma matrix between field operator change and chirality in Peskin and Schroeder (page 165)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, dirac-matrices, scattering-cross-section, chirality

I'm reading Compton scattering in Peskin's book (page 165) and there is a sentence I can't understand.

[image]

The third sentence in the above paragraph says that three $\gamma$-matrix between field operator guarantee that if the initial electron is right-handed, the final electron is right-handed. Additionally, in the next page, there is a sentence says two $\gamma$-matrix will convert a right handed-electron into a left-handed electron. Therefor I think in the amplitude between field operator the even number of $\gamma$-matrix will change the chirality while odd number $\gamma$-matrix will keep it.

I can't understand why it is the case that the even number of $\gamma$-matrix in the amplitude between field operator will change the chirality while odd number $\gamma$-matrix will keep it.

In fact, somebody had asked this question [Why three gamma matrix between initial and final electron lead to the same helicity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/674914/) but nobody gave an answer, so I ask this again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the original equation (5.97), write $\gamma^i$ except $\gamma^o$ for $\overline{u}$, explictly

$$iM=...\overline{u}(p')\gamma^u\frac{\gamma^\alpha p_\alpha-\gamma^\beta k'_\beta+m}{(p-k')^2-m^2}\gamma^\nu u(p)$$

observe:

For right hand spinor, $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ *\\ \end{pmatrix},$ we have $\gamma^\mu \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ *\\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0 & \sigma^\mu \\ \overline{\sigma}^\mu & 0\\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ *\\ \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}\sigma ^\mu *\\ 0\\ \end{pmatrix}$

For left hand spinor, $\begin{pmatrix} *\\ 0\\ \end{pmatrix},$ we have $ \gamma^\nu \begin{pmatrix}*\\ 0\\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0 & \sigma^\nu \\ \overline{\sigma}^\nu & 0\\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}*\\ 0\\ \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}0\\ \overline{\sigma}^\nu *\\ \end{pmatrix}$

Thus every $\gamma^\alpha$ "flip" $\begin{pmatrix} *\\ .\\ \end{pmatrix}$ once and pick either $\sigma^\alpha$ or $\overline{\sigma}^\alpha$, and

in the original equation, two the dominate term had three $\gamma$, as $m$ is negligible in relativistic limit.

We begin with $u(p)=\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ u_R\\ \end{pmatrix}$, terms like

$$\overline{u}(p')\gamma^u \gamma^\alpha p_\alpha \gamma^\nu \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ u_R\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

$$=\overline{u}(p')\gamma^u \gamma^\alpha p_\alpha \begin{pmatrix} \sigma^\nu u_R\\ 0\\\end{pmatrix}$$

$$=\overline{u}(p')\gamma^u \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ \overline{\sigma}^\alpha p_\alpha \sigma^\nu u_R\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

Here, we write $\overline{u}(p')$ in terms of $\gamma^o$ but it does not pick up any $\sigma$ but just flip once more.

$$=u^+(p') \gamma^o \begin{pmatrix} \sigma^u \overline{\sigma}^\alpha p_\alpha \sigma^\nu u_R\\ 0\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

$$=u^+(p') \begin{pmatrix}0\\ \sigma^u \overline{\sigma}^\alpha p_\alpha \sigma^\nu u_R\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

$u^*(p')$ should be something like $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ u_R^*\\ \end{pmatrix}$ for non-zero result.

$$=u_R^+(p') \sigma^u \overline{\sigma}^\alpha p_\alpha \sigma^\nu u_R(p) $$

$$=u_R^+(p') \sigma^u (\overline{\sigma}. p) \sigma^\nu u_R(p) $$
Thus both $u(p)$ and $u(p')$ are right hand and similarly you collect term by term, (5.99) is derived.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to show an answer of my question based on my personal understanding.  The changing of chirality is in fact the result of below relation.

$\overline{u}(p^{\prime})\gamma^{\mu}(\frac{1+\gamma^{5}}{2})u(p)= u^{\dagger}(p^{\prime})(\frac{1+\gamma^{5}}{2})\gamma^{0}\gamma^{\mu}(\frac{1+\gamma^{5}}{2})u(p)=\overline{u}_{R}(p^{\prime})\gamma^{\mu}u_{R}(p)$

$\overline{u}(p^{\prime})\gamma^{v}\gamma^{\mu}(\frac{1+\gamma^{5}}{2})u(p)= u^{\dagger}(p^{\prime})(\frac{1-\gamma^{5}}{2})\gamma^{0}\gamma^{v}\gamma^{\mu}(\frac{1+\gamma^{5}}{2})u(p)=\overline{u}_{L}(p^{\prime})\gamma^{\mu}u_{R}(p)$

If the chirality of initial particle is determined, the chirality of the final particle is determined automatically according to the number of $\gamma$ matrix between field operator.

This is my current understanding, and I hope it could help people who is confused about it.